# JavaFX - Extends Stage, but inherited method is undefined

Tags: javafx, undefined

I'm working with JavaFX using Java 8 and I have a class where Stage is extended. I got this code from another student and it works fine for everyone else, but for me I get an error on setAlwaysOnTop. It says the method is undefined, but it is inherited from Stage. It seems to be only that method which is giving this error.

It would be easier with an image, but I can't post images yet so I had to just copy-paste the relevant code:

```
public class NotificationWindow extends Stage {

public void showNotification(){
        Rectangle2D screenBounds=Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
        this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);      //Error here
        this.setX(screenBounds.getMaxX()-scene.getWidth());
        this.setY(screenBounds.getMaxY()-scene.getHeight());
        this.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: What java version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`alwaysOnTop` property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#alwaysOnTopProperty) was introduced in JavaFX 8 update 20. So you are probably using an earlier version. Update to the latest JavaFX version and it should recognize the method.